# Prove that for every integer $x ∈ \mathbb Z$, the number $x^{102} − x^2$ is a multiple of $2020$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I believe this is to do with modular arithmetic, maybe along the lines of factorising $2020$ into primes and working with totients .
$2020= 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 101$.
The Euler totients of $4,101,$ and $5$ are $2,100$ and $4$ respectively. I am unsure of how to proceed further.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4081712/edit) to show the factorization of $2020$ and then consider the [totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of the resulting prime powers. Effectively we are a small step beyond [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: $\,2^2\cdot 5\cdot 101\mid n^2(n^{100}-1)\,$ by $\,e=2,f=100\,$ in the simple Theorem in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite as:

$$x^{102}-x^2=x(x^{101}-x)$$

Due to Fermat little theorem:

$$x^{101}-x\equiv 0 \bmod 101$$

Rewrite as:

$$x^{102}-x^2=x^2[(x^{25})^4-1]$$

$(x^{25})^4-1\equiv 0 \bmod 5$

$\phi(4)=2$

$\Rightarrow (x^{50})^2-1\equiv 0\bmod 4$

$\Rightarrow x^{100}-1\equiv \bmod 20$

Finally:

$$x^{102}-x^2\equiv 0\bmod (4\times 5\times 101=2020)$$

Comment: See the comment under my answer.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

0. $2020=4×5×101$ which factors are pairwise relatively prime.
1. Prove the given function is a multiple of $4$.  Use the fact that squares are all in $\{0,1\}\bmod 4$.
2. Prove it's a multiple of $5$.  Use Fermat's Little Theorem which asserts $n^p\equiv n\bmod p$ for prime $p$.
3. Prive it's a multiple of $101$.  See (2).

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.